# Yii2: Pagination of more complex query results in aggregated way (when multiple records belong to one record)

Tags: php, pagination, yii2

Yii2:

I'm developing an eshop using Yii2. I have a DB query that returns records like this:

```
 Id | Name       | Size | Color
---------------------------------
 01 | NY Jacket  | L    | light blue
 01 | NY Jacket  | XL   | light blue
 01 | NY Jacket  | XL   | dark blue
 02 | LA Jacket  | M    | yellow
 02 | LA Jacket  | L    | yellow
 02 | LA Jacket  | XXXL | yellow
```

I need all of these data. More preciselly, I need to create one thumbnail for each Id, but need to put the other values into the thumbnail, so that a user knows what sizes and colors are available.

The thing is, though, that I need just 15 thumbs on a page. So that I need to set the pagination, which seems to be problem. The only solution for this that came to my mind was to run two queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id from Products
SELECT * FROM Products
```

So the first query I use for pagination, which works as I have always 15 products on page. Then I have result from the second query, which contains all products that I found (based on the criteria - the query is just an example). Then when printing the thumbnail for each productId I iterate over all products and search for matching records using a foreach loop.

Everything works, but the problem is that when I do foreach loop for each product, it is sooooooo sloooooooooow and i think it's not really the most efective and proper way.

I was also trying to adjust the "all products" query using *andFilterWhere* method, but it doesn't work since it keeps the filter in the query in the next iterations, even though I cloned ActiveDataProvider object. :(

Any help is very appreciated as it really drives me crazy.

Comment: Have you thought about setting up the second query as a relation and then eager loading it using ->with()?

Comment: I have completely redesigned the models and controllers and got rid of the extra time. Have no idea, though, what was the issue. :/ (I have also used later release of Yii)

Comment: you definitely need to define the relations in your models so that you don't get into this mess